# Unable to apply SQL Server 2005 SP4 ENU on SQL 2005 ESN Installation

Tags: sql-server-2005

[image]I want to upgrade existing SQL Server 2005 Express (SP3) with Advanced Services (x86) ESN (Spanish) to SQL Server 2014 Express Advanced Services.
Before i upgrade I need to patch SQL Server 2005 with SQL Server 2005 Express with advanced Services - Service Pack 4 KB2463332.
The one i downloaded is ENU (English) version and when i try to apply the patch it is unable to proceed further.
[image]

I tried to changed the Server OS Language settings from Espana to English but it didnt worked. There is no seperate ESN language SQL 2005 SP4 Express advanced available on the microsoft update site.

Please help to fix this issue.

Thanks,
Vimal

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to install a new version on a new server and migratie to there?

Comment: Also if you're going through the process of upgrading, why [2014 which is end of life already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/sql-server-2014)? Mainstream EOL was back in 2019, and extended EOL is 1.5 years away. You should do something newer like 2019.

Comment: There are 56 such SQL instances running SQL 2005 express and running on Win 2008 R2 OS. There are no plans to upgrade or built a new server with latest OS. So we have only option is to perform inplace upgrade to SQL 2014 Express. I know we have option of backup dbs  / logins and uninstalling SQL 2005 and install SQL 2014 and restore dbs and logins. But we want the direct upgrade option instead of uninstall.  Thanks.